# SqlNullValueException: Data is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. When I try to enter a view(razor page) that contains a form I get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

Note: I do not get the error when I try to send the form but when I enter the view (razor page) that contains the form.

This error appears ONLY when I go to the model and give the string property a `[Required]` data annotation tag. If I delete the tag it works (without the validation ofc)

```
public class Category
{
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Display Order")]
        [Required]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Display Order For category must be greater than 0")]
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: the `Name` property causes the error

My question: why is the error showing when I enter the page and not when I send the form with a blank `Name` property? In short, why do I get this error?

The razor page code is:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCtesting01.Models.Category>

<div class="container p-3">
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Category List</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Create New Category</a> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    @if(Model.Count() > 0)
            {
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Category Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Display Order
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Buttons
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        @foreach(var obj in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50%">@obj.Name</td>
                                <td width="30%">@obj.DisplayOrder</td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                                        <a asp-controller="Category" asp-route-Id="@obj.CategoryId" asp-action="Edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                                        <a asp-controller="Category" asp-route-Id="@obj.CategoryId" asp-action="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }   
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    }
    else
            {
                <p>No category exists.</p>
            }
</div>
```

The error is on line 15:
AspNetCore.Views_Category_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml

```
@if(Model.Count() > 0)
```

Comment: what the property gives the error? And can you the razor page and mark where do you have this error, pls?

Comment: I edited the question hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

You model is null, you didn't send any. Add some validatiton, it will fix the exception

```
 @if( Model!=null && Model.Count() > 0)
.....
```

and since you are using a loop I highly recommend you to change model to this, it will allow you to submit data if you need

```
@model List<MVCtesting01.Models.Category>
```

pls post your action if you want to know how to create a correct model